# python pandas slice string based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to slice a string in a column based on the values in two other columns (ideally method-chained):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["abcde", "abcdefg"], 'start':[0,3], 'end':[3,5]})
df.assign(c = lambda x: x.a.str.slice(x.start,x.end))
```

returns:

```
         a  start  end    c
0    abcde      0    3  NaN
1  abcdefg      3    5  NaN
```

expected:

```
         a  start  end    c
0    abcde      0    3  abc
1  abcdefg      3    5  def
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apply:

```
df.assign(c = lambda x: x.apply( lambda s: s['a'][s.start:s.end],axis=1))
```